# Angular TypeError on Selection

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

In my code, the user can select a printer from a dropdown and then when he clicks the button print, the content will be printed by the selected printer. I get the error below. I initialize the IPrinter but I keep getting the same error. How can I fix that?

[image]

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100" fxFlex.gt-xs="50" class="w-100-p py-8">
    <mat-label>Yazıcı Adı</mat-label>
    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedPrinter" name="selectedPrinter" [compareWith]="comparePrinter" >
        <mat-option *ngFor="let prm of printerList" [value]="prm">
            {{prm.Name}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

TS:

```
selectedPrinter: IPrinter = {};
printerList: IPrinter[];
selection = new SelectionModel<IStickerData>(true, []);
constructor(
    private _productionService: ProductionService,
) {
    _productionService.onPrinterListChanged.subscribe(
        (response: IPrinter[]) => {
            this.printerList = response;
        }
    );
}
comparePrinter(o1: IPrinter, o2: IPrinter): boolean {
    return o1 && o2 && o1.PrinterId === o2.PrinterId;
}
printSticker() {
    this.confirmDialogRef =
        this._dialog.open(FuseConfirmDialogComponent, {
            disableClose: false
        });

    this.confirmDialogRef.componentInstance.confirmMessage = 'Etiket yazdırmak istiyor musunuz?';

    this.confirmDialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
        if (result) {
            this.selection.selected[0].SelectedPrinter =
                this.selectedPrinter;
            this._productionService.printStickerData(this._stickerData).subscribe((response: IStickerData) => {
                this._stickerData = response;
                this._messages.Show("Etiket yazdırıldı", "BAŞARILI", 3);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: After this `selection = new SelectionModel<IStickerData>(true, []);` what you have in `this.selection` object?

Comment: `this.selectedPrinter;` has the correct selection, actually. With the selection's ID, name all that

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, you cannot set the property. [Link](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/cdk/collections/selection-model.ts) of code. Use the method to set selected item.

```
  /**
   * Selects a value or an array of values.
   */
  select(...values: T[]): void {
    this._verifyValueAssignment(values);
    values.forEach(value => this._markSelected(value));
    this._emitChangeEvent();
  }
```

So it will be something like:

```
this.selection.select([this.selectedPrinter]);
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work. Gave an error of `error TS2559: Type 'IPrinter[]' has no properties in common with type 'IStickerData'.`